# VS Code remote debug to NodeJs in cluster

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I am trying to remotely debug NodeJs application, which uses `cluster`s. When I run my app locally, and I am attaching to it, VS Code see child processes and breakpoints works:

[image]

VS Code Config:

```
{
  "name": "Attach",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "port": 50131,
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
  "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
},
```

VS Code result:

[image]

However, in remote host, process starts same way, same port, I am able to attach debugger to it, but VS Code Can't see child processes and source maps (to connect local files breakpoints to remote, in debug config I have correct host address):

[image]

So the difference between local env and remote is Windows vs Unix, and in remote app is run via Forever (module, however, even Forever, without clusters remote debugging works correct).

Where can be an issue?

EDIT: I can't use SSH debug in my organization.

Answer (score 3):

Give vscode extension `Remote SSH` a try. It let you run remote code locally.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh

Comment: In my organization I can't use SSH to the host.